# profile2 - change default edit path to custom profile

Tags: 7, users

I use profile2 module. After visiting user account, user is able to edit account by clicking on edit tab. It leads to Account secondary tab (user/x/edit). User is presented with empty passwords fields and other fields which can be sometimes confusing.

Question: Is it possible to change this default path to direct user to main profile created by profile2 module? (user/x/edit/main)

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Well actually you can, there is a submodule of the profile2 called "profile pages"

> With profile2 user account settings and user profiles are conceptually
>   different things, e.g. with the "Profile pages" module enabled users
>   get two separate menu links "My account" and "My profile".

Via the included "Profile pages" module profiles can be viewed and edited at their own page and get their own menu link, e.g. "My profile".

with the profile menu paths already setted up for your custom profile then you need to remove the edit tab that points to the default profile edit page of drupal. For delete this tab follow this tutorial http://www.zyxware.com/articles/4159/solved-drupal-how-to-hide-menu-tabs-and-menu-links-in-drupal-7

Then you can add your own edit tab that will link to your custom profile edit page https://www.drupal.org/node/1578582

Comment: Hi, I know about this submodule but it is not the same. It creates a menu item not a tab. I would like to point default edit tab to custom profile edit page.

Comment: you can set a menu path to your custom profile page for example "/mycustomprofile" it has its own edit tab and points to "/mycustomprofile/edit" you can use that page instead of the default drupal profile page, that's it

Comment: menu item and tab are two different things. I need a tab, not a menu item:) There is view and edit tab. I need edit tab to point to profile2 main edit page

Comment: yea that's what Im trying to tell you all this time, I have edited the answer, that's what you need to do